# How to convert this variable to string in Perl

Tags: perl

I am using the Linux::SysInfo class to get some information of a remote system, the variable $si (sysinfo) is not in string format when returned, how would it be possible to convert its output to string format?

```
package Hello;
use Linux::SysInfo qw/sysinfo/;
sub hello {
my $si = sysinfo;
return SOAP::Data->name('result')->type('string')->value($si);
}
1;
```

At current, I think it returns a HASH value, as the client says:

> String value expected instead of HASH reference

Answer (score 4):

What value from sysinfo are you interested in? uptime for instance could be returned by

```
return SOAP::Data->name('result')->type('string')->value($si->{uptime});
```

If you really want ALL the info then Data::Dumper may well be the best way.

For multiple return values you could use Data::Dumper:

```
use Data::Dumper;
...
return SOAP::Data->name('result')->type('string')->value(Dumper $si);
```

Or you could store multiple values in the SOAP::Data object with different names and return it.

Comment: Thanks, but how could I specifiy mulitple options? E.g. uptime and totalram?

Comment: It's a multilevel structure, you cannot just "stuff" it into a single return value. I'll edit my answer to try and help more.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data%3a%3aDumper) or [JSON](http://p3rl.org/JSON) to have the data in string form.

```
package Hello;
use Linux::SysInfo qw/sysinfo/;
use JSON;

sub hello {
    my $si = sysinfo;
    my $j = new JSON;
    return SOAP::Data->name('result')->type('string')->value($j->encode($si));
}

1;
```

Comment: Could you provide an example pleas?e

Answer (score 0):

Flexibility is easy to achieve through parametrization.

Pass the sub an additional parameter to decide what value to return:

```
sub hello {

    my ( $wanted_param ) = @_;
    my $si = sysinfo;

    return SOAP::Data
             ->name( 'result' )
               ->type( 'string' )
                 ->value( $si->{$wanted} );
}

say hello 'uptime';    # Returns uptime value
say hello 'totalram';  # Returms totalram value
```